# Prevent video playing call in jasmine

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an angular function on a button doing the following:

```
vm.play_btn_clicked = function() {
        document.querySelector("#culture-video").play()
        vm.play_btn_visible = false;

    }
```

I want to test this function in jasmine, but only the boolean part of it. However, when i try to test it with the following:

```
expect(vm.play_btn_visible).toEqual(true);
    vm.play_btn_clicked();
    expect(vm.play_btn_visible).toEqual(false);
```

I get that querySelector() returned null. Is there a way to either bypass this call or to have a mock object responding to the querySelector()?